# showing every ideal of some quotient ring is principal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and $A=\mathbb F[t]/(t^2)$, where $(t^2)$ is the ideal of $\mathbb F[t]$ (This quotient ring is not an integral domain as you know), and I write an element of $A$ by $[at+b]$, where $[at+b]$ denotes $at+b+(t^2)$.

My goal is to show that every ideal $I$ of $A$ is a principal ideal.

I think, we can divide the problem by $4$ cases.

1. $I=([0])$
2. $I$ (ideal) has an element of the form $[at]$, $a \neq 0$: Then, $I=([at])$
3. $I$ has an element of the form $[b]$, $b\neq 0$: Then, for every element $[ct+d] \in A$, $[ct+d]=[b][b^{-1}(ct+d)]$. Hence, $A=I$.
4. $I$ has an element of the form $[at+b]$, $a, b \neq 0$: Then for every element $[ct+d] \in A$, $[ct+d]=[at+b][mt+n]$ where $n=b^{-1}d$, and $m=b^{-1}(c-an)$. Hence $A=I$.

So, I guess that $A$ has only $3$ ideals, namely, $([0])$, $([at])$, $A$.
Is my answer is correct?

Comment: Every quotient ring of a principal ideal ring is a principal ideal ring. Done.

Comment: Is the fact learned in the undergraduate school?

Comment: I don't know, but this doesn't really matter. You can prove it in two lines.

Comment: @JeongNam-ho Really, proving Martin's suggested exercise looks like it's going to be more valuable than some of the answers you've gotten so far. I urge you to try it. Just think: let $D$ be a PID. The ideals of $D/I$ look like $J/I$ for $I \subseteq J\lhd D$. Your question is "must $J/I$ be principal?" Well $J$ is principal in $D$... does that give you any ideas for a generator of $J/I$?

Comment: @rschwieb you are right. Your argument is more obvious! Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically right; your description just needs a little fine-tuning to remove some clutter.

If you know what is a vector space, then the following can be a more compact answer:

$k[t]/(t^2)$ is a vector space of dimension two over $k$, with $\{1,t\}$ being a basis. Therefore it can be checked that $(0),\ (t),\ (1)$ are the only ideals.

Comment: Is $k[t]/(t^2)$ a vector space?????

Comment: @JeongNam-ho: Yes. In fact $k[t]$ and the ideal $(t^2)$ in it are vector spaces over $k$ and we are looking at the quotient vector space. If you have difficulty in understanding this now, you can come back after learning about vector spaces.

Comment: Is the quotient vector space learned at the graduate school?
Anyway, can't my argument be applied?

Comment: Your argument is mostly correct. It only needs some cleaning(like for example what is mentioned in the other answer). The argument using vector spaces is simply the same proof using different language.

Comment: But, in the azimut's answer, he pointed out my defalt. So, the case 2 in my argument can't be explained.

Comment: Don't worry; it is easy to fix. You just have to note that it will then reduce to 3. or 4.. Try to see it.

Comment: If I modify the case 2 as the following, then is my argument is true? : 2. Every element of $I$ (ideal) is of the form $[at]$, $a \neq 0$: Then, $I=([at])$

Comment: Yes, it will be correct. Please also explicitly state that $a, b, c, d$ belong to $k$. It is always best to specify which sets each element belongs to.

Comment: Yeah...Thanks a lot! By the way, is the fact that K[t] and ($t^2$) are vector space learned in the graduate school?

Comment: @JeongNam-ho : No, not at all. There is no need to go to graduate school for that. If you understand vector spaces and their properties, this should be an easy exercise to prove.

Comment: I have not heard or seen that, but it makes sense that polynimial ring over a field is a vector space. Are there other examples like this?

Comment: Certainly. There are a whole lot of examples that are both rings and vector spaces. They are called "algebras". You should be able to find examples in any book on modern algebra.

Comment: Um...I see~ Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

The final answer is correct. This ring is $A$ is known as the ring of *dual numbers* over $\mathbb F$.

In your points 1.-4., you need to be a bit more careful. For example in 2, you need the additional condition that $I$ doesn't contain an element of the form $[ax + b]$ with $b\neq 0$. (Because then $I = A$.)

Comment: oh, I had a trivial mistake.. Then, isn't my argument applied?